# When user clicks on listview item, open contact list, select contacts, and send sms with listview item data

Tags: android, listview, sms

I'm trying to make an app which the user can store some data in sqlite, which he/she can view later in a listview.

That's the first part of my app.
The second part is when the user clicks on a listviewitem, send via sms the information of that listview item.

How can i acomplish this? Can the user select which contacts he/she wants to send to?

Comment: This may help you: http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing you the links i have used to do these things hope its helps
for Storing in database 
:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

for sending sms:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.putExtra("address", "type phone number...");
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","your message...");
            startActivity(smsIntent);
```

to achive this on list item click follow this:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

for user to select more than one contacts use listView with checkbox:
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html